how to use kaggle python library to run notebook on GPU T4 x 2
from kaggle.api.kaggle_api_extended import KaggleApi
from kaggle.api.kaggle_api_extended import KernelPushRequest
import json

api = KaggleApi()
api.authenticate()

notebook_id = 'notebookbf75a0b38a'

api.kernels_pull(notebook_id, path=r'D:\kaggle\New folder',metadata=True)

api.kernels_push(r'D:\kaggle\New folder')

kaggle pull api download two file one is metadata another one is notebook. even metadata has gpu enable set to true and notebook accelerator set to use nvidiaTeslaT4 (GPU t4x2), notebook always run on gpu p100. either use kaggle api or kaggle python library in both cases no matter what to do notebook not running in GPU t4x2.
What should I do to run notebook on GPU T4 x 2.
